# Comparação de C# mobile para Desktop

Tags: c#, android

Eu sou um mancebo no mundo da programação, a linguagem qual resolvi aprender foi o C#, e me dei bem em aprender. Esses dias uma amiga minha me deu uma ideia boa para um app mobile durante uma conversa sobre estudos, mas quando fui tentar executa-la(agora de madrugada) me veio a duvida: Existe alguma diferença entre a linguagem Desktop para a linguagem mobile, mas especificamente android?

A duvida que tenho é por exemplo, um código de um botão(falando de GUI'S) que é executado por um P.C, não importando se é pelo VS, é o mesmo do code de um button executado por uma plataforma androide.

Observação_1: Se houver diferenças exemplifiquem por favor.
  Observação_2: Para o tópico não ser votado como "muito aberto" minha duvida é mais especificamente para interface gráfica, já que uma coisa é mouse e teclado e outra uma tela touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, existe muita diferença no modo de desenvolver, mas não na linguagem.

A linguagem C# é exatamente a mesma em qualquer plataforma. Sintaxes e features da linguagem vc terá em qualquer plataforma que for desenvolver. Por isso ela é tão bacana. Vc aprende uma linguagem e pode entregar produtos para qualquer plataforma: Desktop, Store App, Mobile, Xbox, Web, IoT, Cloud, Scripts, etc...

Mas o modo de desenvolvimento muda completamente de uma plataforma para outra. Isso se deve pela próprias caraterísticas e ambientes dessas plataformas. Web é orientado a request, Desktop à eventos, Mobile Apps existem preocupações específicas da plataforma, IoT é um loop infinito, Cloud em escalabilidade e desacoplamento, Xbox em um nível de performance que em outras não nos preocupamos, Scripts então é outro mundo. Mas tudo isso com o mesmo C#.

Tentando me aproximar da sua pergunta:

> Uma função executada por um botão em um App desktop, pode ser executada por um botão de um App mobile?

- Resposta simples: **SIM**
- Resposta correta: **Depende**

Se a função a ser chamada tiver um bom nível de desacoplamento - não tiver dependências - pode ser feito de forma bem suave.

Um exemplo legal. Vc faz um WinForms para somar dois números:

```
protected void btnSomar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var primeiro = int.Parse(txtPrimeiro.Text);
    var segundo = int.Parse(txtSegundo.Text);

    lblResultado.Text = (primeiro + segundo);
}
```

Função simples, mas muito mal escrita, pois possui um altíssimo nível de acoplamento e dependências. Para fazer uma soma, ela depende de ter um `object`, argumentos `EventArgs`, dois `TextBox`'es e um `Label` para exibir o resultado. Migrar isso para outra plataforma é impossível. Realmente terá que codificar tudo de novo.

Mas, se isolarmos a função de somar assim:

```
public interface IAdicao
{
    int Somar(int primeiro, int segundo);
}
public class Adicao : IAdicao
{
    public int Somar(int primeiro, int segundo)
    {
        return primeiro + segundo; 
    }
}
```

Podemos usa-la em nosso WinForms perfeitamente:

```
private readonly IAdicao _adicao = new Adicao();
protected void btnSomar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var primeiro = int.Parse(txtPrimeiro.Text);
    var segundo = int.Parse(txtSegundo.Text);

    var resultado = _adicao.Soma(primeiro, segundo);

    lblResultado.Text = resultado.ToString();
}
```

A primeira vista, parece que complicamos mais, mas não. Pois agora, no clique no botão vc tem apenas algunas conversões para capturar dados da tela e depois exibir resultado. Mas o mais importante, sua regra de negócio, a função principal `Soma()` está isolada completamente, sem nenhuma dependência, e pode ser portada para um app mobile, para um IoT, para Web, que irá funcionar sem problemas e sem precisar mexer em anda no seu código.